# Modify validation of fieldset in Mezzanine/Django

Tags: django, django-models, mezzanine

How could I modify Mezzanine keywords to validate differently?

Source code of admin: http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/_modules/mezzanine/blog/admin.html

**I need to do the following validation:**

```
This is a tag --> thisisatag
Tag --> tag
tag --> tag
```

How could I modify the fieldset for keywords for a blogpost If I unregister the blogpost and register it again and doing a deepcopy?

**This is my current code:**

```
blogpost_fieldsets = deepcopy(DisplayableAdmin.fieldsets)
blogpost_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(1, "categories")
blogpost_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].extend(["content", "allow_comments"])
blogpost_list_display = ["title", "user", "status", "admin_link"]
if settings.BLOG_USE_FEATURED_IMAGE:
    blogpost_fieldsets[0][1]["fields"].insert(-2, "featured_image")
    blogpost_list_display.insert(0, "admin_thumb")
blogpost_fieldsets = list(blogpost_fieldsets)
blogpost_fieldsets.insert(1, (_("Other posts"), {
    "classes": ("collapse-open",),
    "fields": ("related_posts",)}))
blogpost_list_filter = deepcopy(DisplayableAdmin.list_filter) + ("categories",)


@admin.register(BlogPost)
class BlogPostCustomAdmin(TweetableAdminMixin, DisplayableAdmin, OwnableAdmin):
    """
    Custom admin class for blog posts.
    """

    fieldsets = blogpost_fieldsets
    list_display = blogpost_list_display
    list_filter = blogpost_list_filter
    filter_horizontal = ("categories", "related_posts",)

    def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        """
        Super class ordering is important here - user must get saved first.
        """
        OwnableAdmin.save_form(self, request, form, change)
        return DisplayableAdmin.save_form(self, request, form, change)


admin.site.unregister(BlogPost)
```